# Add text search where clause to SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, jena

I have been given what I thought would be a simple task - take an existing SPARQL query and adapt the WHERE clause to restrict results to entities where a specific text field contains a specific search term.

However, I am entirely new to the SPARQL language and nothing I've tried is working. It seems I need to use the `text:query (rdfs:label 'word' 10)` syntax, but I haven't managed to successfully integrate this into the query below.

What I need is to further filter the results of the below query where the rdfs:label triple has a value containing the search term. If any of you could provide guidance about how I need to change the query I'd be very grateful.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE 
{
  { SELECT  ?object ?label ?accessionNumber ?image  WHERE {
      ?object a my:Object .
      ?object my:accessionNumber ?accessionNumber .
      ?object  rdfs:label ?label .
      ?object my:maker <http://id.my.org.uk/agent/1234> .  
  }}  

  OPTIONAL  { 
    ?object my:preferredAsset ?asset .
    ?asset a my:Asset .
    ?asset dcterms:hasVersion ?image .
    ?image my:role 'thumbnail' .  
  }  
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Approximate Matching**

***String Matching***

[Joshua Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1281433/joshua-taylor)'s comment points out an excellent and elegant solution to do exactly what you asked for:

```
filter contains( lcase(?label), "word").
```

You can also use regular expressions via the [`REGEX` Filter Function](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex). You would simply add an additional filter to your query such as:

```
FILTER regex(?label, "*word*", "i") .
```

This would allow you to retrieve all labels that contain `word` (case-insensitive).

***Jena Text***

The syntax `text:query (rdfs:label 'word' 10)` you mentioned is part of the `jena-text` project. Note that you must [configure jena-text](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/text-query.html#configuration) for it to work. The primary time that you want to use that is if you want to perform approximate text matching ie: if it's acceptable to search for `word` and get back things like `words` or `wordpress` etc.

**Exact Matching**

Another alternative is exact matching. You can do this by specifying an initial binding, or by modifying your query directly.

***Query Modification***

Modifying your query would produce one of several variations. Not all of these variations are considered equal (Plain Literals / Language Literals / Typed Literals), so you need to be careful when searching to know that your data will match.

```
 ?object  rdfs:label "word" .
 ?object  rdfs:label '''word''' .
 ?object  rdfs:label "word"@en .
 ?object  rdfs:label "word"^^xsd:string .
```

***Binding Specification***

Constructing an initial binding usually looks something like this (psuedocode):

```
final QuerySolutionMap initialBinding = new QuerySolutionMap(){{
     this.add("?label", model.createTypedLiteral(someString));
}};
final QueryExecution e = 
         QueryExecutionFactory.create(query,model,initialBinding);
```

Note that the second argument to `add` has the same choices as the query modification. You can create a language literal or a plain literal rather than a typed literal. Again, it needs to match your underlying data.

Comment: for doing case insensitive matching, you don't need all the power of `regex`, though.  You can just do `filter contains( lcase(?label), "word")`.  That may be a bit cheaper, since the matching is simpler.

Comment: Fantastic, comprehensive answer. Thank you (and @joshua-taylor) - right now a case-insensitive text match is sufficient, but I wasn't aware of the jena-text project and this will definitely be something we'll look at going forward. Grateful to you both.